# In dockerized python3 ftp command RETR throws a ConnectionResetError

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ftp, ftplib

I try to download a file via ftp from inside a python3 docker container, The container was built form the official docker hub python repository.

Here is a minimal example of the python code I try to execute:

```
import ftplib

ftp = ftplib.FTP("ftp.geneontology.org")
ftp.login()
ftp.sendcmd("MDTM /go/ontology/go-basic.obo")
ftp.retrbinary("RETR /go/ontology/go-basic.obo", callback=open("go-basic.obo", "wb").write)
```

This code's MDTM and RETR command works well in the host.

However, in the python3 docker container only the MDTM command works. The RETR command throws the following error message:

```
>>> ftp.retrbinary("RETR /go/ontology/go-basic.obo", callback=open("ich.obo", "wb").write)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 443, in retrbinary
  data = conn.recv(blocksize)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
>>>
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

I build, enter the container and python shell with this sequence:

```
docker build --tag bue/py3ftp .
docker images
docker run -ti --name=abc bue/py3ftp /bin/bash
python
```

My box is configured with the following software:

- OSX 10.11.6 ElCapitan
- VirtualBox version 5.1.8 r111374 (Qt5.5.1) used by docker-machine
- docker-machine version 0.8.2, build e18a919
- docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec
- python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 10 2016, 08:25:20) inside the docker container

Has anyone an idea where the bug lies?
Why this is not working?
Maybe a port that I have to open or something?

Grateful for any input!
Best, 
Elmar

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the bug.
Instead of:

```
docker run -ti --name=abc bue/py3ftp /bin/bash
```

use:

```
docker run -ti -P --name=abc bue/py3ftp /bin/bash
```

or:

```
docker run -ti -p 21:21 --name=abc bue/py3ftp /bin/bash
```

Elmar